Spring test expected 400 bat was 404 no found endpoint
I have the next controller:
    @Operation(summary = "Create a student meeting for agency ")
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content = {
                    @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = MeetingResponse.class), mediaType = "application/json")
            }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", content = {
                    @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class), mediaType = "application/json")
            }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", content = {
                    @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class), mediaType = "application/json")
            }),
    })
    @PostMapping(path = "/student/meeting")
    public MeetingJoinToken setupMeeting(@RequestBody StudentMeetingRequest studentMeetingRequest){
        SetupMeetingRequest setupMeetingRequest = validateAndCreateSetupMeetingRequest(studentMeetingRequest, ParticipantRole.ATTENDEE);
        return studentService.setupMeeting(setupMeetingRequest);
}

And also I have the next test:
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ThApplication.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.agency")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc

public class ControllerIntTest {

    private final String patientMeeting ="/student/meeting";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    IamTokenManagerRepository iamTokenManagerRepository;

    @MockBean
    ConfigmapFilesDownloader configmapFilesDownloader;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {
        AthenaLogInitializer.getInstance().initialize();
    }

    @Test
    public void th_joinSession_BadRequest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/student/meeting"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest());
    }
}

After running the test I got
Expected :400
Actual   :404

I guess I am missing something in the configuration of the test, any ideas?
These are my dependencies:
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure'
testImplementation 'junit:junit'
testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-test'


sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom(testImplementation)
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(testRuntimeOnly)
}

Thanks!

Your controller is not created into the context. Most likely due to missuse of
@SpringBootTest(classes = ThApplication.class)
and
@ComponentScan.
Ideally, put single @SpringBootApplication into the classpath, remove classes and @ComponentScan and than it may work depending on your compliance with Springs convention-over-configuration :)
Alternatively use @MvcTest and pinpoint controller classes in order to test actual MVC layer.

I added @SpringBootTest(classes = ThApplication.class) because if not the test tries to start the spring app and I got several dependencies issues, you said remove @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.agency") and leave just @SpringBootTes?

For testing MVC layer, use @WebMvcTest. For proper use of SpringBootTest fix your dependencies and do integration tests against mostly complete application.

If I add something like just @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class) I stared getting errors such as  Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@21ff56e7 testClas
